# Is it possible to define and later redefine a variable in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In `python` I can easily define and redefine a variable.

for example,(let the variable be `sum`):

```
>>> sum=0
>>> y=[1,2,3,4]
>>> for n in y:sum+=n
>>> sum
10
```

is it possible to do same in `django templates`??

i tried:

```
{% with sum=0 %}
 {% for emp in employees %}
  <!--i dont want to print, but just redefine the variable sum -->
  {{ sum|add:emp.credit }}
   ......... 
 {% endfor %}
 <!-- now i want to print the sum. it is easy-->
 {{ sum }}
{% end with %}
```

Comment: You need to put the `{{ sum }}` within the `{% with sum = 0 %}` block. That said, you should try to avoid performing logic in your templates and move that to the view where possible

Comment: Why can't you do this in view itself and pass on the resulting value to template? Do you have any specific requirement for this?

Comment: @Sudipta now i think it is better to create a template filter. ie `{{ employees|get_emps_credit }}`. I hopes to use @alecxe's answer(`Employees.objects.all().aggregate(total_credit=Sum('credit'))['total_credit']`) in creating the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a job for templates.

Better define `sum` in the view and pass it to the template in the context, e.g.:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total_credit = Employees.objects.all(). \
               aggregate(total_credit=Sum('credit'))['total_credit']

return render_to_response('templatename.html', 
                          {'total_credit': total_credit}, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: thanks :). what about creating a template filter. ie `{{ employees|get_emps_credit }}`. I hopes to use `return Employees.objects.all().aggregate(total_credit=Sum('credit'))['total_cre‌​dit']` in that filter

Comment: @suhail well, if you've already passed employees to the template, you can sum `credit` values in the custom filter using python's sum, like this: `return sum(e.credit for e in employess)`. But this is also a way of putting logic in templates. See also similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748356/summarizing-inside-a-django-template.